# Is it possible in Paypal to create pre authorization of customers account in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

Is Paypal have any functionality like Stripe off_session

Here in stripe, we are using like:

- user add their billing detail which directly stores in stripe and stripe respond customer id and payment intent id
- When users order something from the site, we directly request the money from the default stripe payment intent id and customer id, so this doesn't require user-approval directly the billed amount deduct from the stripe.
  But in PayPal, I am not able to find any way to manage this. Please let me know if I missed checking any flow

Link to stripe:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/pay#pay_invoice-off_session

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.